# ExtJS 3.4 :: Combobox in grid - wrongly selecting first value when opened

Tags: extjs, combobox, grid

Using ExtJS 3.4

I have a EditorGridPanel and columns with ComboBoxs.

Just noticed that if I three options, say...

- Dog
- Cat
- Mouse

...and Mouse is the saved value, then when I click the dropdown, my field gets populated with Dog - without me selecting it. Whatever the options, my field gets populated with the first value.

This only happens after an initial page load and the first time I click a combobox. Subsequent combo clicks do not elicit this behavior.

Anyone experienced anything like this? Any clue?

Thanks

Paul

Comment: Hmm. I removed the typeAhead:true setting from the Combobox config and this behavior goes away. That's not right, but it gets me where I need to be right now...

Answer (score 0):

```
autoSelect : false
```

for combobox component will solve this. Read ExtJS Documentation for more details.